# How to add separators in Jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need to get a list of IPs like this one (values in quotes,comma separated and no spaces).

```
['172.16.1.67','172.16.1.68','172.16.1.69']
```

To do so, I'm trying to call for a jinja2 template in my playbook. The content of the template is:

```
[{% for servidor in groups['servidores'] %}{{ hostvars[servidor].ansible_host}}{% endfor %}]
```

This template is generating this string:

```
[172.16.1.67172.16.1.68172.16.1.69]
```

I tried to use filters and things I found but no matter how I tried, I end up with errors (as most of answers I found assume that the reader know how to apply the provided solution which is not my case). My guess is that I should apply a "join" filter, but I don't know how to do it.

Could you please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the IPs with quotes and append them to a list first before joining them with `','` in the output:

```
{%- set ips = [] -%}
{%- for servidor in groups['servidores'] %}
    {% do ips.append("'%s'" | format(hostvars[servidor].ansible_host)) %}
{% endfor -%}
[{{ ips | join(',') }}]
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense !!!:) Althogh for some reason is not workin :( 
The error message contains: "...Encountered unknown tag 'ips'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endfor' or 'else'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'for'.." I've tried different things but did not get it to work yet

Comment: Oops I wrote the code in a haste and forgot to put curly braces around the output. Please try again.

Comment: I got it!!! Thank you so much for your help!!! I did have to change it a little bit (it took me a while to realize what was wrong. So after changing the "{%" and "%}" in the 3rd line of your code, for "{{" and "}}" accordignly, it worked like a charm :)
Again, thank you very much for your  help!!! :) I would upvote all your comments, but I don't have enough reputation to vote for anything, sorry about that :/

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to be correct? (That is, click on the grey check mark next to a question.)

Comment: Done! Sorry about that :)
Also, if you would like to edit it with the fix that make it work (is only a detail but it doesn't work otherwise), this is the working one:
{%- set ips = [] -%}{% for servidor in groups['servidores'] %}{{ ips.append("'%s'" | format(hostvars[servidor].ansible_host)) }}{% endfor %}[{{ ips | join(',') }}]
Have a great day!

Comment: Ah you're right that I forgot that one needs to use the [`do` statement](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#expression-statement) in order to invoke `ips.append`. It isn't a good practice to use `{{` and `}}` for a `None`-returning function call like `append` after all. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: omg...I dont have reputation even to chat but there is this red sign asking me to move this discussion to chat :D Anyways, that's another thing you just teach me right there. I'll adapt my code to follow that good practice and again, thank you very much!!! :)